# Rewrite .htaccess to prevent user visit "index"

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Here is my .htaccess, I used 404 customised page and hide .html and .php extension. But when I prevent user input .html and .php, they also can visit `http://example.com/index` and subfolder `http://example.com/folder/index`. I used relative url to link images and assests, users input "index" will make it unlinked. How to use .htaccess to redirect any "index" to /error404.html?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error404.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.(?:html|php)\s [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/error404.html
  RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

# Remove .html-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solve it half....
The code is here:

```
<Files "index">
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/error404.html
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
</Files>
```

It just work in `http://example.com/index`, only work in root directory, for another subfolder, it's not work. Anyone have better answers?

**UPDATE:**

```
<Files "index">
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/error404.html
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
</Files>
<Files "folder/index">
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/error404.html
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
</Files>
```

This code is a stupid way to slove, but if I have thousand of folders, it will very complex.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this method can redirect all "index" to the error page with error 404.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/error404.html
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```

But something wrong when http://example.com/ load. The js and css file seems like unlink. Use back stupid method can access js and css file.